# what type of associations

Tags: database

I have PATIENT and VISIT table.
VISIT has foreign key as Patient_id and repeated rows. But PATIENT does not have any foreign key from VISIT.

What type of relation exist with PATIENT and VISIT. One to many? or Many to one?

Comment: Just state it in business terms and you will have your answer. "A Patient will make one or more visits to the facility" aka Patient to Visit is One to Many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One patient has many visits, so One to many... ;)